# Linq with boolean function to relational db in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Probably a few things wrong with my code here but I'm mostly having a problem with the syntax. Entry is a model for use in Entries and contains a TimeStamp for each entry. Member is a model for people who are assigned entries and contains an fk for Entry. I want to sort my list of members based off of how many entries the member has within a given period (arbitrarily chose 30 days). 
A. I'm not sure that the function I created works correctly, but this is aside from the main point because I haven't really dug into it yet.
B. I cannot figure out the syntax of the Linq statement or if it's even possible.

Function:

```
        private bool TimeCompare(DateTime TimeStamp) 
    {
        DateTime bound = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);

        if (bound <= TimeStamp)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Member list:

```
    public PartialViewResult List()
    {
        var query = repository.Members.OrderByDescending(p => p.Entry.Count).Where(TimeCompare(p => p.Entry.Select(e => e.TimeStamp));

        //return PartialView(repository.Members);
        return PartialView(query);
    }
```

the var query is my problem here and I can't seem to find a way to incorporate a boolean function into a .where statement in a linq.

***EDIT***
To summarize I am simply trying to query all entries timestamped within the past 30 days.

I also have to emphasize the relational/fk part as that appears to be forcing the Timestamp to be IEnumerable of System.Datetime instead of simple System.Datetime.

This errors with "Cannot implicitly convert timestamp to bool" on the E.TimeStamp:

```
var query = repository.Members.Where(p => p.Entry.First(e => e.TimeStamp) <= past30).OrderByDescending(p => p.Entry.Count);
```

This errors with Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' and 'System.DateTime'

```
var query = repository.Members.Where(p => p.Entry.Select(e => e.TimeStamp) <= past30).OrderByDescending(p => p.Entry.Count);
```

***EDIT2***

Syntactically correct but not semantically:

```
var query = repository.Members.Where(p => p.Entry.Select(e => e.TimeStamp).FirstOrDefault() <= timeComparison).OrderByDescending(p => p.Entry.Count);
```

The desired result is to pull all members and then sort by the number of entries they have, this pulls members with entries and then orders by the number of entries they have. Essentially the .where should somehow be nested inside of the .count.

***EDIT3***

Syntactically correct but results in a runtime error (Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.
Parameter name: key):

```
var query = repository.Members.OrderByDescending(p => p.Entry.Where(e => e.TimeStamp <= timeComparison));
```

***EDIT4***

Closer (as this line compiles) but it doesn't seem to be having any effect on the object. Regardless of how many entries I add for a user it doesn't change the sort order as desired (or at all).

```
        var timeComparison = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30).Day;
        var query = repository.Members.OrderByDescending(p => p.Entry.Select(e => e.TimeStamp.Day <= timeComparison).FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Are you simply trying to make the query only grab records within a given time frame?

Comment: @mituw16 Yes. OrderByDescending number of entries within a 30 day period. But the query is against the members and only relationally against the count of entries and the timestamp.

Comment: @GamerJ5 with your second edit, let me get the scenario straight. You want to get all members. then take the entry, and sort them by their timestamp? or did you want to just sort them by number of entries?

Comment: @DylanCorriveau Take all members first, sort them by the count of entries but only if those entries are within a certain period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help Dylan but here is the final answer:

```
    public PartialViewResult List()
    {

        var timeComparison = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30).Day;
        var query = repository.Members
                  .OrderBy(m => m.Entry.Where(e => e.TimeStamp.Day <= timeComparison).Count());

        return PartialView(query);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of research dictates that Linq to Entities (IE: This section)

```
...var query = repository.Members.OrderByDescending(...
```

tends to really not like it if you use your own functions, since it will try to map to a SQL variant.

Try something along the lines of this, and see if it helps:

```
var query = repository.Members.AsEnumerable().Where(TimeCompare(p => p.Entry.Select(e => e.TimeStamp).OrderByDescending(p => p.Entry.Count));
```

Edit: I should just read what you are trying to do. You want it to grab only the ones within the last X number of days, correct? I believe the following should work, but I would need to test when I get to my home computer...

```
public PartialViewResult List()
{
    var timeComparison = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);
    var query = repository.Members.Where(p => p.Entry.Select(e => e.TimeStamp).FirstOrDefault() <= timeComparison).OrderByDescending(p => p.Entry.Count));

    //return PartialView(repository.Members);
    return PartialView(query);
}
```

Edit2: This may be a lack of understanding from your code, but is e the same type as p? If so, you should be able to just reference the timestamp like so:

```
public PartialViewResult List()
    {
        var timeComparison = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);
        var query = repository.Members.Where(p => p.TimeStamp <= timeComparison).OrderByDescending(p => p.Entry.Count));

        //return PartialView(repository.Members);
        return PartialView(query);
    }
```

Edit3: In Edit3, I see what you are trying to do now (I believe). You're close, but OrderByDescending would need to go on the end. Try this:

```
var query = repository.Members
    .Select(p => p.Entry.Where(e => e.TimeStamp <= timeComparison))
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Entry.Count);
```

Comment: That will probably work, but be cautious of throwing the `.AsEnumerable()` in in the query, as that will cause the entire result set to be pulled into memory and then Linq will work with objects, instead of letting SQL server do the processing.

Comment: True enough, but there wouldn't really be any way to let SQL do the processing, since the comparison is done on the code side...

Is it not?

Comment: @DylanCorriveau very similar to what mituw16 had said(and since deleted) but for both I'm receiving the error "Operator '>=' Cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.DateTime>' and 'System.DateTime'

Comment: check my edit for a solution. I forgot select returned an enumerable object vs just a normal object

Comment: @Dylan In reply to edit2: p is the Member model whereas e is the Entry model that's lazy-loaded by the entity framework through the Member model. I don't have the code in front of me at the moment but I know that method does not work either.

Comment: @GamerJ5 ok. That's fine. I wasn't sure if they are one in the same. BTW, I edited my first example to include a FirstOrDefault() call after the entry. That should resolve the System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' and 'System.DateTime' issue.

Comment: @DylanCorriveau Much closer but not quite. Although that does help me with the enumeration problem (thanks, I was trying to cast to list and index and was failing terribly) it's still not the desired result. See Edit2 of original post for why.