# Lazy Loading to OrderBy number of Entries per Member

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have an Entries table for entity Entry which contains:

```
public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
```

I have a Member table for entity Members with:

```
public virtual ICollection<Entry> Entry { get; set; }
```

Entries contains a FK to Members (MemberId) in order to assign entries to specific member IDs, When an entry is created it is created for a specific MemberID.

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_Entries_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([MemberId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Members] ([ID])
```

Members contains no FKs (Should it?).

**My goal is to sort a list of members based on the number of entries they have WITHIN the past 30 days.** I.E. return the whole list of members and then order them from 0 entries to however many they have that have occurred within the past 30 days.

I believe I have the syntax correct for the query (Thanks @DylanCorriveau):

```
var timeComparison = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30).Day;
var query = repository.Members.OrderByDescending(p => p.Entry.Select(e => e.TimeStamp.Day <= timeComparison).FirstOrDefault());
```

The code is compiling but the orderby doesn't seem to be having an affect so I have a feeling it might be how I have the tables/EF set up.

Is this the correct implementation of a one-to-many relationship in EF/Sql?

Is there a way to debug or set breakpoints so that I might see the actual number of entries being pulled so I can tell whether my EF setup is incorrect or my query is?

In order to query the Entries through the Member table is a FK needed? Or does the EFdbContext make this link?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23550925/1043380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, you want to order by the `Count` of `Entry` for a given member where the `Entry` meets your timestamp criteria, like this:

```
var query = repository.Members
                      .OrderByDescending(m => 
                                         m.Entry
                                          .Where(e =>
                                                 e.TimeStamp.Day <= timeComparison))
                                          .Count());
```

To debug/verify the counts that EF is returning, you can use a slightly modified version of the same, but select an anonymous type that contains the `Member` Id and a count of entries that match the criteria:

```
var results = repository.Members
                        .OrderByDescending(m => 
                                           m.Entry
                                            .Where(e =>
                                                   e.TimeStamp.Day <= timeComparison)
                                            .Count())
                        .Select(m => new {
                            MemberId = m.Id,
                            Count = m.Entry.Where(e => 
                                                  e.TimeStamp.Day <= timeComparison)
                                           .Count()
                        });
```

Comment: Thanks! that was the answer. I will do the second part through unit testing to ensure everything is working correctly but it appears to be.

Comment: As a side note, I'm not sure your date logic is doing what you want it to do.  I'd suggest changing the `Where` clause to not compare the integer value of the `Day` property, like this: `Where(e => e.TimeStamp >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30))

Comment: Actually, assuming you only care about the date (5/12/2014) and not the exact timestamps of when entries were created, you should use the `Date` property of the `DateTime` class in your comparisons...I've updated my answer to include this.

Comment: That change (The first comment) results in a runtime error (LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.) Can you explain the difference between the two commands and what you think mine is doing? (Not being argumentative, I wasn't entirely sure I had it written correctly myself) Thanks.

Comment: Your changed answer causes a runtime error: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: Hmm, it turns out the `AddDays` method and the `Date` property are not supported in EF since they can't be translated into SQL...I haven't run into that issue before.  I'll change my answer back to the one that compiled and ran since I don't have time to investigate further at the moment.

Comment: Yes, this is what I've been running into for a week now, many syntax's tried and failed. Yours appears to be syntactically and semantically correct as I've been creating entries for members in the db and watching the member list as it is sorted. I would definitely love to know if it's not actually doing what I think it is doing though so if you get a chance to investigate please update. Thanks.